# How to input a matrix and output a vector in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

I need to input a 100 x 36 matrix and get a vector output of 100 elements. Something like:

```
0     0 1 0 2 0 0 ... 1
1     0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0
.     . . . . . . .   .     ===>  [0 1 1 0 0 1 ... 0] (first output here (0) corresponds to
.     . . . . . .  .  .                                the first row in the matrix, second to
.     . . . . . .   . .                                second row and so on)
99    1 1 0 0 1 2 ... 1
```

Sorry, I don't know if there is a way to format the matrix (tried something I read on math.meta but didn't work).

How can I do that? I've watched and read about tensorflow but they use the data they have and doesn't match my case. For now the data is produced by the script I have or maybe I can export that to a csv (though not sure how I will save several matrices for each input to the NN be one matrix and not mix other matrices rows)

Comment: Do you have code that you attempted this with? Consider that matrices and vectors can be represented using the same data structure, it's just how *you* utilize it.

Comment: @Djinn What do you mean? In code (the output produced by the code) is a list of lists for the matrix, eg like the code above  [[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, ... 1], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... 0] ...] thats for the input matrix and the output its just a simple list [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 ... 0] . I have this (of course values change) after each file I process and I have like 3000 files so would be the 3000 matrices for input and 3000 vectors for output to train the NN. But very new to deep learning so I dont know how to get that data in and get that output also to correspond like I said (first to first row, etc).